# Code executes fine inside try block, but if try is not present it fails

Tags: c#, .net, white-framework

I have the code:

```
try
{
    IUIItem menuItem = menu.Get(SearchCriteria.ByText(criteria));
    menuItem.Click();
}
```

It only succeeds when in try block section (no exception). If the try block is omitted (no try), it does throw an execption. It seems impossible to me , but that's the way it is. Why ?

Comment: Can you edit your question to add your `catch` block?

Comment: can u post some code before & after this try block. & whats the exception ?

Comment: Are you sure it succeeds? Please show your catch block

Comment: I suspect [pokemon exception handling](http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html)... Please show [MCVE] so behavior can be explained.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look up the definition of a try-catch. When you have a try-catch, the exception is still being thrown, but the try-catch handles it so your code can keep running. Without a try-catch the program will break because there is nothing there to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

This code will not compile without the catch statement. If you e.g. have:

```
try
{
    IUIItem menuItem = menu.Get(SearchCriteria.ByText(criteria));
    menuItem.Click();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

the code will compile and throw an exception that is catched but nothing is done with it so you will not notice anything.

If you add:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    throw ex;
}
```

you will write the exception message to the console and then rethrow (forward) the exception.